# How to optimize the inner query mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
insert into abc(id,item_id,item_type,l_id,c_id)
Select '',o.id,'Open',pl.id,'67' from pls pl, opens o where o.id IN
(select id from Open where not exists (select 1 from ps where type = 'Open' and item_id = opens.id)) and o.type = pl.name;
```

I have huge data..
Help would be appreciated!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the select switching the use of IN to joins:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT '', o.id, 'Open', pl.id, '67' 
FROM pls pl
INNER JOIN opens o ON and o.type = pl.name
INNER JOIN open op ON and o.id = op.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ps ON ps.type = 'Open' and ps.item_id = opens.id
WHERE ps.item_id IS NULL
```

I have added DISTINCT in case the id on the open table is not unique. If it is unique then this can be omitted.

The LEFT OUTER JOIN checks for a matching record on the PS table, and if there is on it is returned. If not the columns from that table are returned as NULL. Then in the WHERE clause the non null ones are omitted from the results.

However for efficiency the indexes on the tables are important. Is there an index on type on the opens table? An index on id on the open table? An index covering type and item_id on the ps table?

Comment: Yes I have index on all the given fields. we have used inner join twice can we able to perform it in single join... I have not much idea  of inner join please ignore if it sounds dumb

Comment: It is using INNER JOIN once per table. The only way you can avoid that is using `IN(SELECT....)` which tends to be poorly optimised in MySQL or `EXISTS(SELECT....)` , which in this case I think would probably perform poorly due to requiring a correlated sub query (ie, the sub query checks against a value from outside the query, and needs to be executed for each row).

Comment: My final query is INSERT INTO ps(id,em_id,em_type,l_id,c_id)
    SELECT '',o.id,'Open',pl.id,'67' FROM pls pl
    INNER JOIN opens o ON o.type = pl.name
    INNER JOIN opens ON o.id = opens.id
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ps WHERE em_type = 'Open' AND em_id = opens.id);

Comment: Problem is the sub query that you use for NOT EXISTS refers to opens.id. So it will need to be executed many times (the LEFT OUTER JOIN solution avoids this).

Comment: Hi, Kickstart I have more complicated query than the above -
Where have 5 tables 
Table A => Field id, 
Table B => Fields id, a_id, c_id, 
Table C => Fields id, name, 
Table D => Fields id, name, 
Table E => Field id, a_id, d_id

From A Need to get B,... from B needs C name,... 
Then compare C name with D name and get D id....
if equals then create a records in E with a_id and d_id.
 
Could you please help me in getting the query from inner join

Comment: This should really be a new question. Can you post it up as a new question, with table layouts and sample data please, and what you have so far (even if that doesn't work). Makes it a lot easier to figure out what is required.

Comment: Kickstart i have add query on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24612233/how-to-create-the-inner-query-wtih-5-different-tables-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
  insert into abc(id,item_id,item_type,l_id,c_id)
  Select '',o.id,'Open',pl.id,'67' from pls pl
  INNER JOIN opens o ON o.type = pl.name 
  INNER JOIN open ON  o.id = open.id 
  where not exists (select 1 from ps where type = 'Open' and item_id = opens.id)
```