# How to create the inner query wtih 5 different tables mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

```
Having 5 tables 
Table a_dates = id, 
Table b_types = id, a_date_id, c_type_id, 
Table c_types = id, name, 
Table d_profiles =  id, name, profile_type 
Table e_ps = id, a_date_id, d_profile_id
```

From a_dates Need to get b_types,...then from b_types needs c_types name,... Then compare c_types name with d_profiles name and get d_profiles id.... if equals then create a records in e_ps with a_date_id, d_profile_id.

Could any one please help me in getting the query from inner join.

I tried like, it is incomplete query

```
    INSERT INTO e_ps(id,a_date_id,a_date_type,d_profile_id,c_id)
    SELECT '',a.id,'A',dp.id,'67' FROM d_profiles dp
    INNER JOIN a_dates a ON {HERE I NEED NAME MATCHING WITH c_types name} = dp.name and dp.profile_type = 'A'
    INNER JOIN a_dates ON a.id = a_dates.id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN e_ps eps ON eps.a_date_type = 'A' AND eps.a_date_id = a_dates.id
    WHERE eps.a_date_id IS NULL
```

Comment: refer : http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx It will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a relatively simple JOIN:-

```
INSERT INTO e_ps(id, a_date_id, d_profile_id)
SELECT NULL, a_dates.id, d_profiles.id
FROM a_dates
INNER JOIN b_types ON a_dates.id = b_types.a_date_id
INNER JOIN c_types ON b.c_type_id = c.id
INNER JOIN d_profiles ON c_types.name = d_profiles.name
```

With joins there are several types, and I suspect you are getting confused. Briefly:-

- With an INNER JOIN it looks for a match that is on BOTH tables. If no
  match the no record is returned.
- With a LEFT OUTER JOIN it takes a record from the table on the left
  and looks for a match on the table on the right. If a match great,
  but if not then it still brings a row back but the columns from the
  table on the right just have values of NULL.
- A RIGHT OUTER JOIN is very much the same, just with the tables
  reversed (most people including me avoid using this as it has no
  advantages most of the time but just makes things confusing).
- With a FULL OUTER JOIN it gets the records from both side, whether
  they match or not. If they match then the columns from both are
  returned, if not matched then the columns from one are returned. Not
  that MySQL does not support a FULL OUTER JOIN (although there are
  ways to emulate it).
- A CROSS JOIN joins every combination of 2 tables. These are used when
  there is no common column to match on but you want all combinations.
  For example if you wanted a table of all employees and all days of
  the week for each employee you would cross join a table of days of
  the week against a table of employees (then for useful data you might
  LEFT OUTER JOIN a table of holidays to the result).

Comment: Hey thanks Kickstart for your explanation. It worked perfectly :)